# How to insert text into a list that is typed in an input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
import React, { Component, createElement } from "react";

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  state = {
    todo: [],
    inputValue: "",
  };

  addTodo = () => {
    this.setState({ todo: [...this.state.todo, this.state.inputValue] });

    // I want to insert separate paragraph tags (todos from this.state.todo) into the list element here
  };

  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if (this.state.inputValue === "") return;

      this.addTodo();
    }
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="list"></div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="insertTodo"
          placeholder="Add a new todo!"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

I am creating a Todo List where the user types into an input, and the todo is then inserted into the `div` with class `list` element. I'm new to React so I don't know the best way I should go about doing this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` the array, inside the `.list` div, and render each todo item, by wrapping it in  `p` tag. I have added a `button` element, to handle the `addTodo()` function.
Also, you may want to move the `.list` div, below the input.

```
import React, { Component, createElement } from "react";

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  state = {
    todo: [],
    inputValue: ""
  };

  addTodo = () => {
    this.setState({ todo: [...this.state.todo, this.state.inputValue] });

    // I want to insert separate paragraph tags (todos from this.state.todo) into the list element here
  };

  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if (this.state.inputValue === "") return;

      this.addTodo();
    }
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="list">
          {this.state.todo.map((todo) => {
            return <p>{todo}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="insertTodo"
          placeholder="Add a new todo!"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-pascal-txh55?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, it is saying that I have to assign a unique key prop to each child, does this affect the code? As it is working fine.

Comment: @Ramen_Lover912 React uses the `key` prop, to handle minimal DOM changes. I would recommend to use unique `key` prop. you can even write a function to generate random numbers...Ex: `<p key={todo + Math.random()}>{todo}</p>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    class TodoList extends Component {
      state = {
        todo: [],
        inputValue: "",
      };
    
      addTodo = () => {
        // I want to insert separate paragraph tags (todos from this.state.todo) into the list element here
        // Hint: when you want to add a todo, you simply set input value to empty here.
        this.setState({
          todo: [...this.state.todo, this.state.inputValue],
          inputValue: "",
        });
      };
    
      handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          if (this.state.inputValue === "") return;
          this.addTodo();
        }
      };
    
      handleChange = (e) => {
        // Hint: I prefer adding "...this.state" every time before updating.
        this.setState({ ...this.state, inputValue: e.target.value });
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            {
              // Hint: use React fragment ("<> ... </>") when there's 
              more than one element in the first level.
            }
            <div className="list">
            {
              // Hint: Adding the current list with map in here
            }
              <ul>
                {this.state.todo.map((t, i) => (
                  <li key={i}>{t}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
    
        {
          // I would prefer adding it inside a form element and instead of onKeyDown, use onSubmit on the form
          // (on enter it will submit automatically, but you will have to do an e.preventDefault() to not refresh the page).
        }
        <input
          type="text"
          className="insertTodo"
          placeholder="Add a new todo!"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a working example with a few comments. Also setState runs asyncrounously so it's not a good idea to run multiple one at the same time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` like TechySharnav mentioned is a quick way of doing it. But if you need to do some more complex operations/layout stuff, then writing a custom function and calling it in the `render` jsx might be cleaner. So, you could have a function like:

```
renderItems() {
    var rows = []
    this.state.todo.forEach((elem, idx) => {
        // for example
        rows.push(
            <p>{elem}</p>
        )
    });

    return rows;
}
```

Then call it inside `render`:

```
//...
<div className="list">
   {this.renderItems()}
</div>
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

js map will certainly solve the problem.
this small snippet for printing the list,

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="list">
           { this.state.todo.map((item) => {
              return <p>{item}</p>
           })}
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="insertTodo"
          placeholder="Add a new todo!"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
        />
    );
  }
```